# Where can I get up to date country list?

Tags: internationalization, country, country-codes

I need to get list of valid countries for web application, is there any list that could be downloaded as XML or similar format, so that I could atomatically update country list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get the [ISO 3166 list](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists.htm) (there is an [XML version](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_3166-1_list_en.zip)) from the [ISO 3166 Maintenance agency](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes.htm). You can also look at [Updates on ISO 3166](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/updates_on_iso_3166.htm). You can read about the [standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166) on Wikipedia for more information.

Comment: First two links are dead

Answer (score 3):

You can get a JSON list of country codes to names at http://country.io/names.json, and other country related data at http://country.io/data/

Answer (score -2):

Here is the curated and regularly updated source of "country list" data available in CSV and JSON formats:

https://datahub.io/core/country-list

To get the data in CSV:

https://datahub.io/core/country-list/r/0.csv

JSON:

https://datahub.io/core/country-list/r/0.json